# React test fails becasue target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run component tests and the tester keeps on failing because the target container is  not a DOM element. I found an answer that recommended removing exported values from index.tsx but it did not fix the issue.

```
src/Component/__tests__/FirstPage.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Target container is not a DOM element.

       8 | export const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');  
       9 | 
    > 10 | ReactDOM.render(
         |          ^
      11 |   <React.StrictMode>
      12 |     <App/>
      13 |   </React.StrictMode>,

      at Object.render (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26091:13)
```

Here is my App.tsx file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './App.css';
import FirstPage from './Component/FirstPage/FirstPage';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <FirstPage/>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the index.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

export const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint
reportWebVitals();
```

And here is the test

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';
import FirstPage from '../FirstPage/FirstPage';
import User from '../User/User';

const testUser = new User("testUser", "id")



test('Test if FirstPage includes enter lobby button', () => {

    render(<FirstPage/>);
    const textElement= screen.getByText(/Enter Lobby!s/i);
    expect(textElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>

    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<!--
  This HTML file is a template.
  If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

  You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
  The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

  To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
  To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

After spending some time on your project I found out what was causing this issue with your tests. In some of the components that `FirstPage` is using, you were importing socket like that

```js
import { socket } from "../.."
```

This caused unexpected behaviour in the tests because the path was wrong.

To fix this, I took the socket export from `index.tsx` and put it in `App.tsx` and wherever you need to import it you can just do lit like this

```js
import { socket } from "../../App"
```

That resolves the issues with the tests. Also, the improvements mention above still apply for cleaner code .

First of all, in your `App.tsx` you are importing `FirstPage` and name it as `Greeting` but then you are returning `FirstPage` in your component. You need to either return `Greeting` or rename the import to `FirstPage`. Also, you need to import `React` in order for the code to work. Even if you don't use `React` explicitly, you still need to import it because JSX is tranpiled to `React.createElement()` which uses `React`.

```js
// App.tsx
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FirstPage from "./Component/FirstPage/FirstPage";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <FirstPage />;
  }
}
```

Moving on to your test, it's a good practice to put all the tests inside `__tests__` folder. Also, it looks like you don't actually import `FirstPage` as well and then try to use it. Try importing it and running the tests again with the proposed changes in the `App.tsx`.

```js
// /Components/FirstPage/__tests__/FirstPage.test.tsx
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import FirstPage from '../FirstPage';

test("Test if FirstPage includes enter lobby button", () => {
  render(<FirstPage />);
  ...
});
```

I've tried it in the codesandbox and the tests worked.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Greeting was a typo there I now edited it. Imported react and FirstPage in the test as well but it is still failing.

Comment: Does the ID attribute that you are taking in the ReactDOM.render in your 
 index.tsx is the same as in `index.html` @DanielBenedek? Also would be good if you edit your question with the code in your `index.html`.

Comment: Yes it is root in both places. Except in `index.tsx` it is 'root' and the div in `index.html` is id="root".

Comment: I've added my `index.html` in the question.

Comment: @DanielBenedek do you have the code on version control system (e.g. GitHub)? I would then be able to check it on my local machine.

Comment: Yes I do, however it is a private project on a private gitlab server.

Comment: Can this be a version issue with react? or ts? I'm using the most up to date 17.0.0.1 for react and 4.0.5 for ts

Comment: No, the versions shouldn't be responsible for this. I've tried to reproduce this on my local machine with your files and it does work for me. I suspect there's something else in your codebase that's causing this.

Comment: Are you ok to share `FirstPage` and `User` code?

Comment: I've added you on fb, maybe I could send through the zip version of the project